# why $("#id").val() isn't a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

jsp :

```
<input id="companyName" class="cpn" type="text" value="" ></input> 
<input id="phoneNumber" class="number" type="text" value=""></input>    
<textarea id="remark" placeholder="消息备注"></textarea>
<input  class="submit" type="button" onclick="apply()" value="在线提交" ></input>//define some block<input>
```

js :

```
var companyName = $("#companyName").val();//get the value in block<input>
var phoneNumber = $("#phoneNumber").val();
var remark = $('#remark').val();
```

firefox and google shows .val() isn't a function,so i change the code:

```
var companyName = document.getElementById("companyName").value;
alert(companyName);// not use the jquery
var phoneNumber = document.getElementById("phoneNumber").value;
alert(phoneNumber);
```

now it gets the vaule,but ajax code still can't work:
can anyone tell me?

Comment: Please edit your answer to include actual code blocks, not images.

Comment: ajax:     if (checkName() && checkPhone()) {
  $.ajax({
   type : "POST",
   url : ctx + "/applySettlement/applySettlementSave",
   cache : false,
   dataType : 'json',
   data : {
    companyName : companyName,
    phoneNumber : phoneNumber,
    remark : remark,
   },
   success : function(result)

Comment: If `$("...").val()` is not a function, then `$` does not represent the JQuery object. You must be defining `$` to mean something else after you include the JQuery library (if you have it included at all).

Comment: i just can't understand what you mean...what i think is that $ has been defined in JQuery library,so i include JQuery and can use $,do you mean i need to write my own JQuery?but in other files,$(“#id”).val() works normal@John S

Answer (score 0):

```
# Please try bellow code in javascript #    

 <script>
        function apply(){
            var companyName = document.getElementById("companyName").value;
            alert(companyName);

            var phoneNumber = document.getElementById("phoneNumber").value;
            alert(phoneNumber);

            var remark = document.getElementById("remark").value;
            alert(remark);
        }
    </script>
    <input id="companyName" class="cpn" type="text" value="" ></input> 
    <input id="phoneNumber" class="number" type="text" value=""></input>    
    <textarea id="remark" placeholder="enter"></textarea>
    <button class="submit" onclick="apply();">Submit</button>



# Please try bellow code in Jquery#  


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

    function apply(){
        var companyName = $("#companyName").val();
        alert(companyName);
        var phoneNumber = $("#phoneNumber").val();
        alert(phoneNumber);
        var remark = $('#remark').val();
        alert(remark);
    }
</script>
<input id="companyName" class="cpn" type="text" value="" ></input> 
<input id="phoneNumber" class="number" type="text" value=""></input>    
<textarea id="remark" placeholder="enter"></textarea>
<button class="submit" onclick="apply();">Submit</button>
```